# Autocomplete extender 'extended' across entire data table

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services, autocompleteextender

I have a request to create an auto complete that will search an data table. Is this achieveable quickly and simply or is it a case of writing a reasonable amount of code?

Originally, I have been using a webservice and linq to point at a single column's worth of data (IDDesc) and pull back the list of products:

```
Product.FinalProductsDataContext dbac = new Product.FinalProductsDataContext();

            return dbac.tblProduct
                .Where(r => r.Account== HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountKey"].ToString() && r.IDDesc.Contains(prefixText))
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(r => r.IDDesc)
                .Select(r => r.IDDesc)
                .Take(count)
                .ToArray();
```

However, if I wish the autocomplete to look at all the columns, is it a case of repeating similar LINQ statements for each of the columns contained within the datatable or is there a 'quick fix'?

I personally don't think this is an ideal scenario but it is a request I must work towards.

Any help or advice, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to solve this *entirely* with LINQ (and repeating all those statements for each column in the table, as well as hitting the database repeatedly), I think I'd look to put something in the database to do the heavy lifting here.

You could create a view that takes the fields from the table and amalgamates them into one column e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ProductView]
AS
SELECT     CAST(ProductName AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS 'ProductColumn'
FROM         dbo.Products
UNION
SELECT CAST(SupplierName AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM dbo.Products
UNION
...
```

which if you added the view to your context would then allow you to modify your existing LINQ query and point it at that view e.g.:

```
Product.FinalProductsDataContext dbac = new Product.FinalProductsDataContext();

return dbac.ProductView
    .Where(r => r.Account== HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountKey"].ToString() && r.ProductColumn.Contains(prefixText))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(r => r.ProductColumn)
    .Select(r => r.ProductColumn)
    .Take(count)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: A bit of lateral thinking - I like it! Thanks for the advice.